# Bootstrap accordion icon change with jQuery on a different accordion body opening

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7r0tjLr5/2/

When you open and close a body the icon changes which is great, its just when you open one body then open another without closing the first the incorrect icon remains. I need it to return to the right chevron icon when closed

I have messed about with .(":hidden") but with no successful results.

```
$('#first-panel-span').is(":hidden")
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look:

First of all I added to the HTML the class `accordion-panel`, for each tab So you can handle them together:

```
<p id="first-panel" class="accordion-panel">
```

---

```
$('.accordion-panel').on('click', function(){
    // each tab BUT this, remove 'down' and add 'right' to the span
    $('.accordion-panel').not(this).find('span:first').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-right');
    // toggle 'this' span
    $(this).find('span:first').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-right');   
});
```

**demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7r0tjLr5/6/**

Answer (score 0):

Only solution i can think of here is to reset the class to `'glyphicon-chevron-right'` for every span except the one you have just clicked.